# nginx - Hide proxy host + port + path

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, mod-proxy

Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with nginx 1.4.6

I've got an internet radiostation where people can listen/stream directly from winterradio.com (Example) and got the next configuration for my vhost winterradio.com in nginx:

```
server {
server_tokens off;
listen 80;
server_name winterradio.com;
location / {
proxy_pass http://radiohost.com:1972/radio
 }
}
```

My question is: How can I hide the proxy_pass url+port+folder(mountpoint)  from people who connecting so they only see http://winterradio.com insteed of http://radiohost.com:1972/radio ?
I added the next 2 lines:

```
server_name_in_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port
```

That did allmost the trick but doesn't hide the last part from the proxy address **/radio**, I couldn't find the answer somewhere around.
Is this possible? Can i hide the full proxy address from browsers/radioplayers?

Comment: Can anybody help me with this? I'm stucked!

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved with ssl compiled and enabled in icecast2 & nginx.

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)